# Manually installing Python 2.6?

Tags: python, 8.04

Ubuntu 8.04 comes with Python 2.5 and no 2.6 package support in the apt-get ecosystem. Searching around I found http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/10/installing-python-26-source-ubuntu-hardy/ and all went well except I got a few more missing modules than the article reports;

```
Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_bsddb             bsddb185           dbm             
dl                 imageop            sunaudiodev     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

Im pretty sure i want/need dl. I know it's deprecated starting with 2.6, but it should still be there.

Overall Im finding it very difficult to get 2.6 installed. I would ideally like to replace it (point `/usr/bin/python` at 2.6) but looking in 2.5 site-packages and seeing symlinks to a 'pyshared' directory, etc. makes me fear that things will break terribly.

I also tried to setup a virtualenv on another, 2.6 capable machine and copied over the virtualenv but it cannot execute the python binary.... idunno.

Im really just trying to get 2.6 installed to run a Django project. Nothing more, so it doesn't have to replace the system python but if it can work, it'd be nice.

Comment: Actually, unless it goes by a different name, i cannot import ``dl`` or ``dlopen`` under 2.5 either. So maybe im ok?

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by simply downloading the 2.6 release from python.org and installing it along side 2.5 (`/usr/lib/python2.6/`) and symlinking `/usr/bin/python` to python2.6. A few modules were reported missing during the build process but ignoring them didn't seem to break anything (that i needed, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but there appears to be a backport of Python 2.6 in this PPA:

- https://launchpad.net/~python-dev/+archive/ppa/+packages

Though it has not been updated in quite some time but might get you what you need with less hassle.

Comment: Ahh. Very helpful. I ended up rolling my own, alongside 2.5. I unlinked /usr/bin/python and pointed it to 2.6, etc. and things seems to work alright. *shrug* I luckily don't rely on it too much outside of what im directly trying to setup.